# Is the Kendo UI Web Grid adaptive rendering independent of the Kendo mobile application?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile

I'm trying out the latest Kendo UI Web release with a view to using it in our applications, particularly the Grid component.

As shown [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mobile/adaptive/grid.html) the grid is capable of adaptive rendering on mobile devices, or in any browser if the [mobile](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#configuration-mobile) property is set to "phone" or "tablet". However, I can't get this to work in my code.

Does anyone know if the adaptive rendering is independent of the mobile application functionality in Kendo UI Web or is it a requirement that any adaptive grids are running as part of a Kendo UI mobile application?

I suspect it's the latter. My current code is just using the non-mobile Grid examples with the mobile property set to "phone" and I have not instantiated any instance of the Kendo mobile application (e.g. kendo.mobile.Application(document.body)).

Thanks,
Chris.

ps. Following Taras' response I have some code that demonstrates my problem, adapted from his:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title></title>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/assets/libraries/kendoui.web/2014.1.318/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
    <link href="/Assets/Libraries/KendoUI.Web/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Assets/Libraries/KendoUI.Web/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/Assets/Libraries/KendoUI.Web/2014.1.318/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
              { field: "name" },
              { field: "age" },
              { field: "name" },
              { field: "age" },
              { field: "name" },
              { field: "age" },
              { field: "name" },
              { field: "age" },
              { command: "destroy" }
            ],
            dataSource: [
              { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
              { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
            ],
            filterable: true,
            columnMenu: true,
            mobile: "phone"
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kendo UI adaptive rendering is *independent* part of mobile application functionality. 
Furthermore it is can automatically detect what type of device is using and apply required rendering style.
You can just enable this features by add **mobile: true** (or phone, or tablet) to your grid constructor

```
 <div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
   columns: [
     { field: "name" },
     { field: "age" },
     { command: "destroy" }
   ],
   dataSource: [
     { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
     { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
   ],
   filterable: true,
   columnMenu: true,
   mobile: true
});
</script>
```

If you set is to true, script changes in styling and behavior in order to remain consistent with a device experience (for see difference run page in mobile browser). If you set **mobile:phone** or **mobile:tablet** you will see same result with mobile and desktop browser and auto detect device features turns off.

See examples: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/grid/adaptive

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I've been doing as explained in my question, but I am not seeing adaptive behaviour, so I'm still not convinced it's independent. I have tried your simple extract and it doesn't adapt when resized. I'll paste my code into my question.

Comment: What about add kendo.mobile.all.min.css to your page?

Comment: Taras, I'm marking your answer as the answer since you took the time to put the sample up. The problem was that I misunderstood how 'adaptive' the telerik grid is. I was getting alternative forms for editing and column changes but I also expected the grid to be automatically responsive in changes to device width, which it isn't as far as I can tell. Thanks.